# Elasticsearch aggregations: strategy for accessing additional fields

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am using the following code for aggregations. It only return the Id and I would also like to return the Name. We did a project a few years ago and we indexed a field called idName (separated by |) but it was so messy solution. I am wondering if there are any better ways to do this with the recent version of Elastic?

```
.Aggregations(aggs => aggs
    .Nested("nested_cat", nested => nested
        .Path(p => p.Categories)
        .Aggregations(a1 => a1
            .Terms("terms_cat_id", terms1 => terms1
                .Field(f1 => f1.Categories.First().Id)
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I read there are 2 other options. One is to do a sub-aggregation, however the following doesn't seem to work:

```
.Aggregations(aggs => aggs
    .Nested("nested_cat", nested => nested
        .Path(p => p.Categories)
        .Aggregations(a1 => a1
            .Terms("terms_cat_id", terms1 => terms1
                .Field(f1 => f1.Categories.First().Id)
                .Aggregations(a2 => a2
                    .Terms("terms_cat_name", terms2 => terms2
                        .Field(f2 => f2.Categories.First().Name)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I also read that I can use Scripts, but I haven't gotten that to work either.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the sub-aggregation to work by mapping category.name as "Keyword" instead of "Text"